# Get md5/sha1 hash of a mysql tables data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Long story short, in a globally included config file I grab settings from a table, and define a constant in my code with the settingKey, settingVal from the database table, now I don't think there's that much overhead, however if I ended up with a ton of settings it would be better to check if they've changed and if so define them, otherwise not.

So bottom line, should I/Can I get a hash of a table and compare it to the last known table hash to see if values have changed? Or Am I going about this the entirely wrong way, and there's a more efficient method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a trigger that writes in a log table the time of last update etc.

```
CREATE TABLE LOG (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  tablename varchar NOT NULL,
  action ENUM('insert','delete','update') NOT NULL,
  action_time DATETIME NOT NULL)

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_table1 AFTER INSERT ON table1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log (id, tablename, action, action_time)
     VALUES (null, 'table1', 'insert', NOW())
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_table1 AFTER DELETE ON table1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log (id, tablename, action, action_time)
     VALUES (null, 'table1', 'delete', NOW())
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER au_table1 AFTER UPDATE ON table1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log (id, tablename, action, action_time)
     VALUES (null, 'table1', 'update', NOW())
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that the trigger does **not** fire `FOR EACH ROW` because you only want to the date any change happens and this makes the triggers slightly faster (and the log slightly shorter) when doing multiple updates/delete/inserts.

**Links:**
Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html

Comment: Do the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers include `REPLACE` queries?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Replace translates into a insert or update as needed. If the replace does an update it will trigger the update trigger, if it does an insert it will trigger that trigger. Obviously there is no `replace` trigger. The correct trigger to use is decided on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 2):

A timestamp would be a lot easier, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_modified > somedate
```

MySQL even will automatically update a last_modified column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table
    ADD last_modified TIMESTAMP 
        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then anytime you pull your settings, just take note of the timestamp and use it next time you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's better to cache settings somewhere (in file, in [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) or [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)) and just invalidate cache, if some setting is changed.

No need to hash tables since in some cases the hash of a table file can change without its contents changed (InnoDb adaptive index, for example).